# How to write text on a recording video in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I am using Red 5 server to record video from webcam and netstream to save the record to server.

I have a requirement which will send a text on every 1 minute to the Flash file through JavaScript and I want to  display that text on video. The important thing is that I want to have that text displayed on the video when I play back the recorded stream.

Answer (score 0):

There are no file processing options or on the fly options to send a text into the video.
You have to add for example FFMPEG and write a small batch script that does merge the text into the video.
Search for "FFMPEG add Text" and you will find plenty of examples of such a script.